# Need Help: Publishing to Facebook page wall from my site

Tags: php, facebook

I am from china. This is my first topic. I ran into some difficulties. It is about Facebook wall.

I according to the following website
http://www.moskjis.com/other-platforms/publish-facebook-page-wall-from-your-site , when I enter https://login.facebook.com/code_gen.php?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&v=1.0

It seems that new Facebook version seem `app_id` and `app_key` is same,

my `App_ID/API_Key` is xxxxxxxxxx [blocked sensitive content] replace with `YOUR_API_KEY`, but the result is

```
Error
An error occurred. Please try later
```

My English is poor, do you understand what my issue is? you know, Facebook is cut-out in China. Only a few people use it，so I come to this for help.

[image]

Comment: you really shouldn't display your api key publicly like this. it's a secret between you and facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your secret key and ID shouldnt be the same. Go to developer's app and check from there. Hope this helps

Comment: I find a lot of information,I am sure they are same,and facebook page show data like this(App ID/API Key)